# Calendar - Apply search filter on appointments (Subject)

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS Java api 2.0 to read appointments on a Calendar mailbox.
It works fine but my problem is to filter the appointments by its subject description, which I am not succeeding.
At the moment I am using CalendarView to retrieve the appointments, 
something like this:

```
CalendarFolder cf = CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults3 = cf.findAppointments(view);
```

I know that the Item class provides a method which I can apply a search filter, but it does return occurrences of a recurring series.

Something like that:

```
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(50);
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "OK");
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, searchFilter, itemView);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using FindItems you will get all the recurring masters, which represents the whole series. From masters you can get occurrences and exceptions:

```
Appointment occurrenceOrException = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(service, new ItemId(recurringMasterId), index);
```

with the above you can get occurrence/exception by index.
Note that index starts from 1 and when index is out of range it will throw an exception.

This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633700%28v%3dexchg.80%29

Comment: Thanks, added the essential parts of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I am sorry for the late reply, I had to give priority to another project. Your answer was very helpful, however I will need to find a way to adapt this function to my existing project once I have to deal with the scenario where there will be recurring appointments that the start date is within the period I am filtering but the recurring master is out of the range, then the filter does work, but this would be subject to another thread, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that instances of a recurring appointment (even if they are exceptions) do not physically exist, so they cannot be possibly returned by FindItems().

What you probably want is the [GetUserAvailability operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getuseravailability-operation) (exposed by the [ExchangeService.GetUserAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability?view=exchange-ews-api) Method ) in Detailed mode.